# help free inode but no space with weird percentage

Tags: filesystem, disk, inode

i'm kindof a newbie at this , but when i list the disk usage with df command  ,i get that the percentage of inodes used is 1 percent (%iused = 1%)but the 99% of the filesystem is used ( only 1 percent is free : used : 99% ) How is that possible and what does that mean 
thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire formatted output of 'df' and 'df -i'. There is valuable information in the details.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that you have many big files on this filesystem. Or at initialization the (probably default) ratio of inode per bytes was not the optimum value.

Having "too many" inodes is not a problem per se, the problem is often more when you have too little of them (you can have a lot of space free on your disk but if you do not have any inode free you will not be able to store anything new).

Things also depend on which filesytem you use: ext3, ext4, xfs, reiserfs, btrfs, etc. Have a look at the mkefs specific to your filesystem for explanations on inode usage.

Comment: i'm using LVM, thank you for your response but 1 % of inodes used again 99 % of disk space used ,isn't that too extreme ?(i would understand if it was 30% again 70) but  is that really possible or there's a problem with my filesystem

Comment: You just have too many inodes or too many big files. But if everything works, even if you are in an unusual situation, I do not think there is anything to do nor to be worried about.